# Как на c# определить IPv4 на выходе определенного HTTPS прокси (вида 127.0.0.1:9001)?

Tags: c#, ip

Предполагаю можно через httprequest отправить запрос к ip.ru
Но может есть какой то более универсальный и элегантный способ? вдруг ip.ru упадет или отвечать перестанет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете запустить свой собственный веб-сервер, который будет просто писать ip-адрес в ответ. По-другому никак:

```
using (var listener = new HttpListener())
{
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:12345/"); // задаем порт
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        string response = context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = responseBytes.Length;
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
}
```